# RxJS & Angular HttpClient: How to transform value asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to apply an asynchronous transformation function on the value emitted by an observable.

```
@Injectable
export class ApiService{
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    getSomething(url): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get(url);
    }
}
```

In the code above, I want to apply a transformation function `myFunc`, which returns a promise, on the value emitted by `this.http.get(url)`.

Normally I would use the map operator of RxJS, but since the transformation function returns a promise, I could not find a way to handle it.

For example, let my function be:

```
function myFunc(value){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // modify the value async

        resolve(modifiedValue);

        // ...
    });
}
```

Is there an appropriate way to handle this task? I think the following is not suitable, am I right?

`return this.http.get(url).map(myFunc);`

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Note:** I'm using RxJS 5.5.2

Comment: What makes you think it's unsuitable? Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Yes, I tried. The value I receive was somewhat different than I expected. I got an object like `{__zone_symbol__state: true, __zone_symbol__value
: x}` where is x is what I was expecting, but it's wrapped in another object as you see. I don't know what those zone symbols are though :)

Comment: Then it might help to show a [mcve] *of that*, it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: To clarify your problem I believe you are saying that your mapping function is async (returns a promise) so you can't use the `map` operator with it. Can you change the mapping function to return an observable and then use the `switchMap` operator instead of `map`? Why is your mapping function async btw?

Comment: @bygrace myFunc is a method from a third party library. I'll check the `switchMap`. Thank you.

Comment: @bygrace It would be super if you could provide a simple example.

Comment: OK, then maybe you can do: `return this.http.get(url).switchMap(x => Observable.fromPromise(myFunc(x)));`

Comment: Cool. It worked.. I knew it was that easy but still could not put all together in my head, yet. I'm very new to RX. Thanks again! @bygrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `mergeMap` operator to take in the response value, perform some modification asynchronously via another Observable operation, and then return the modified value. This operator will merge the values emitted by HttpClient and your modifier Observable and return a single Observable that emits the mutated values.

**EDIT**: Including the `Observable.fromPromise` bit from @bygrace's comment for a more complete answer.

i.e.

**EDIT**: For RxJs v5.5+

```
import { pipe } from 'rxjs/util/pipe';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


    @Injectable
    export class ApiService{
        constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

        getSomething(url): Observable<any>{
            return this.http.get(url).pipe( 
                                        mergeMap(myFunc) 
                                      );
        }

        private myFunc(x): Observable<any> {
            // do some asynchronous modification that returns an Observable
            return Observable.fromPromise(x);
        }
    }
```

Pre RxJs v5.5

```
@Injectable
export class ApiService{
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    getSomething(url): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get(url)
               .mergeMap(data => {
                   // do some asynchronous modification that returns an Observable
                   return Observable.fromPromise(data);
                });
    }
}
```

See: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to stick with observable instead of returning a promise. Because the consumers of the ApiService will call subscribe on the object returned by the getSomething method.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your goal. I see someone else suggested using `switchMap` which produces the same output as `mergeMap`. The only difference is they use a different operator internally under the hood.

Comment: @rawkfist0215 to clarify `mergeMap` and `flatMap` are the same. `switchMap` only maintains one inner subscription while `mergeMap` maintains multiple. So there is a subtle difference to be aware of. Essentially use `switchMap` if you want to cancel a request generated by the inner observable when the source emits.

Comment: @rawkfist0215 I want to try mergeMap as well. But I get the following tslint error: `property 'mergeMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'` even though I imported mergeMap from 'rxjs/operators'. Have an idea?

Comment: @hswner You may want to try the `pipe` util operator if you are on a high enough version of RxJs and see if that clears up the tslint error. That's their new recommended best practice. See: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md

Comment: @rawkfist0215 now it's okay. I see that pipe is the way to go ;)